# Implicit differentiation of $\ln(x^2+xy+y^2)=1$

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

Find $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$ of $\ln(x^2+xy+y^2)=1$.

So for this natural log should I start by using the power rule or the the product rule of $xy$? The textbook talks about taking the natural log from both sides.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Hey Jose, thanks for the heads up, I guess I was trying to say that I was getting mixed up on where to start with find the derivative of an implicit function. The textbook my class is using doesn't go over many examples so I was trying to understand how to approach this if I start with taking the natural log of both sides and kind of taking care of the "outer function" before I would be able to use the product rule? Those were the steps I was taking and I was just wondering if that is not enough information? Is there somewhere with a guideline?

Answer (score 2):

Exponentiate both sides of the equation to get that $$x^2+xy+y^2=e$$Take the derivative with respect to $x$: $$2x+y+xy'+2yy'=0$$Solve for $y'$ to get $$y'=-\frac{2x+y}{2y+x}$$

Note: I know the question doesn't follow community standards, but this is a new user who should be given a chance. I'm saying this just in case someone comments me to not answer low-quality questions.

Comment: Even If The user is new,You could have suggested The user to include thier Work,This would have benefitted both user and The MSE,I agree New users should be given chance,But It should only be after they try to work out themselves after suggestions in comments

Comment: @DheerajGujrathi The user already got a comment, so I think it would be repetitive to put another one about the same thing.